# Javascript and W3C validity?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, w3c, w3c-validation

I have the impression that the use of javascript often breaks W3C xhtml/css validity. Is this true? If so, why and is there a way for me to use javascript in my webpages and still have them be W3C valid (html, xhtml, css)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your javascript in a  `//<![CDATA[` tag it will validate

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents

Comment: Don't do that please. It makes me feel like I'm in 1998.

Comment: @Raynos: What makes you feel like that? It's valid HTML and XHTML  so where do you see any problems? In my mind that's exactly what CDATA-section have been intended for.

Comment: Raynos>> I don't like it either and often don't give a damn. But if you target XHTML strict(maybe some other specs too) it is need for some lesser smartphones to be able to render the page. I don't know of any better alternative as this is a very easy fix to apply. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: Writing XHTML makes me feel like I'm in 1998. Also @Dr.Molle It's ugly and annoying. I have yet to come across any browser that crashes without `CDATA` tags.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of your question is yes. 
To avoid this read this link http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#script