# Javascript event W3C compliant

Tags: javascript, events, for-loop, w3c

one questio about this javascript, i want a W3C compliant wersion: but i have no idea.
could you help me ? For HTML 4.01 Transitional Doctype

thanks

```
<script Language = "JScript" for = "Player" event = "OpenStateChange(NewState)">
  switch(NewState)
    {
        // Media object open.
        case 13:
            intervaltime("player")
document.getElementById("temps").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("Player").currentmedia.duration)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Which doctype do you want it to be compliant for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having a gander at this StackExchange post.

[Javascript and W3C validity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057427/javascript-and-w3c-validity)

I would always recommend not being too obsessive about W3C Compliance, especially when it comes to Javascript. Since you want to use a Transitional doctype as well they are much more loose. I'm not saying don't go for full compliance, just don't lose any sleep over it, if it works in all browsers then excellent, what more do you need!

Comment: i understand your answer and i'm agree with you.
But i'm working on a project which need a full W3C compliance.

i read the Javascript and W3C validity Post, but i don't want to use a trick... I just want to learn how to code properly a event like that.

thanks for your help.